# Correct usage of pyInstaller on tkinter project from command line

Tags: tkinter, import, pyinstaller

I want to package my app with pyinstaller. However, my project is already quite complex and I am struggling on how to a) import the dependencies from my own modules correctly and b) create the correct structure within my bundle.

My project has the following folder structure:

```
- BUILD
- DO_NOT_SHARE
    - encrypted_login.py
- library_ZZ
    - ZZ_serial.py
    - ZZ_utilities.py
    ..
- GUI_X
    - images
        - Image.png
        ..
    - GUI_X_V2.py
    - icon.ico
    - requirements.txt
```

My main application is GUI_X_V2.py. From there, I import standard packages, other packages installed with pip such as pymongo and my own modules from library_ZZ. Example on how I import:

```
import os, sys
from pymongo import MongoClient

sys.path.append(".." + os.sep + "library_ZZ")
sys.path.append(".." + os.sep + "DO_NOT_SHARE")

from ZZ_serial import open_serial_port
from ZZ_utilities import shift_bit
```

And this is my call from within the folder BUILD, where I want my generated packages to be.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=../GUI_X/icon.ico --add-data ../library_ZZ;library_ZZ --add-data ../DO_NOT_SHARE;DO_NOT_SHARE ../GUI_X/GUI_X_V2.py
```

However, of course, when executing BUILD/dist/GUI_X_V2.exe i get an error that the module ZZ_serial could not be found. I can work around that by adding the following in my GUI_X_V2.py:

```
from library_ZZ.ZZ_serial import open_serial_port
```

I do not want that, I want to leave my code like it is if possible. In my original structure the library is one level above, and i want to do this packaged automated (maybe create the .spec file once) for many apps. I just do not know how to build the right structure.

Furthermore, when I do mentioned fix, I couldn't execute the .exe because one package imported inside ZZ_serial.py (pySerial - imported as 'import serial') was not included in the bundle. I tried using the following code in my .spec file:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

import_serial = collect_submodules("serial")
total_hidden_imports = import_serial

a = Analysis(hiddenimports=total_hidden_imports,
)
```

This worked, but I could not manage the next error when trying to do this for another package by using collect_submodules("timeit") (used like this from within ZZ_serial.py: from timeit import default_timer as timer). The images folder I did not try to include at all. There must be some better way to do this, right?

Comment: If you project is big, bundiling it all to one file can make it take like 2-5 mins to boot up.

Comment: Okay - thanks! The one-file bundle is not too important to me anyway

Comment: Then you can remove all the add data and compile into a directory and then add all the dependency

Comment: So i just add the dependencies manually by copy/paste?